# Swift viewForHeaderInSection not working with custom colors

Tags: uitableview, swift, uicolor

I'm experiencing very strange behaviour of the tableView's `viewForHeaderInSection` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, tableView.frame.size.width, 30.0)) // Doesn't care about x, y offset
    label.text = "Results"
    label.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor() // Not Working: UIColor(red: 88, green: 130, blue: 202, alpha: 1.0)

    return label
}
```

1. Regardless which values I choose in the `CGRectMake` constructor my label will always stick to the upper left corner.
2. The `textColor` and `backgroundColor` attributes are working with standard UIColor colors e.g. `UIColor.blueColor()`, but failing with colors like `UIColor(red: 88, green: 130, blue: 202, alpha: 1.0)` -> Not showing anything at all

Can you guys help me fix this issue?

Comment: From the UIColor docs: The red component of the color object, specified as a value from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: You guys are awesome! Embarrassing mistake..

Comment: Put the UILabel into a UIView then it should work.

Comment: @yene: Thanks, I tried this just now and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    let newRed = CGFloat(88)/255
    let newGreen = CGFloat(130)/255
    let newBlue = CGFloat(202)/255

    self.init(red: newRed, green: newGreen, blue: newBlue, alpha: 1.0)
```